# na.rm while using 'summarize'

Tags: r, dplyr, na.rm

While studying tidyverse, I found something cannot understand.
The missing data should be excluded with using na.rm = TRUE , so that calculating 'mean' will return a particular value.
However, some gropus reveal NaN instead of a number.

In library 'dplyr', we can use starwars dataset.

```
starwars |> group_by(species) |> summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm=T))
```

The results include NaN and I cannot find why this happened

Comment: Some groups have all NAs, to replicate this issue try: `mean(c(NA, NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`